# How to get na.omit with data.table to only omit NAs in each column

Tags: r, data.table

Let's say I have

```
az<-data.table(a=1:6,b=6:1,c=4)
az[b==4,c:=NA]
az
   a b  c
1: 1 6  4
2: 2 5  4
3: 3 4 NA
4: 4 3  4
5: 5 2  4
6: 6 1  4
```

I can get the sum of all the columns with

```
az[,lapply(.SD,sum)]
    a  b  c
1: 21 21 NA
```

This is what I want for `a` and `b` but `c` is NA.  This is seemingly easy enough to fix by doing

```
az[,lapply(na.omit(.SD),sum)]
    a  b  c
1: 18 17 20
```

This is what I want for `c` but I didn't want to omit the values of `a` and `b` where `c` is `NA`.  This is a contrived example in my real data there could be 1000+ columns with random NAs throughout.  Is there a way to get `na.omit` or something else to act per column instead of on the whole table without relying on looping through each column as a vector?

Comment: Does `az[,lapply(.SD,sum,na.rm=TRUE)]` work?

Comment: @BlueMagister  I didn't think of that.  Yes, it does work for `sum` although it doesn't work for functions that don't have that argument built in.  Unless there's a better approach I could write my own functions that are just na.omit of my desired function which will be better than looping through the column vectors.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor use a lambda in that case, e.g., `az[,lapply(.SD, function(x) length(na.omit(x)))]`

Comment: @MatthewPlourde thanks I didn't know you could make functions on the fly like that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Expanding on my comment:

Many `base` functions allow you to decide how to treat `NA`. For example, `sum` has the argument `na.rm`:

```
az[,lapply(.SD,sum,na.rm=TRUE)]
```

In general, you can also use the function `na.omit` on each vector individually:

```
az[,lapply(.SD,function(x) sum(na.omit(x)))]
```

Comment: Ok this is basically the same as what I was suggesting by making na.omit functions of what I need to do except done on the fly. I didn't realize you could do that.